# Output Underscore upside down in c++

Tags: c++, output, ascii, console-output

I'm trying to output an ascii `0175` in c++

```
 cout << "¯¯¯¯¯¯ E\n" << endl // the "E" is there for comparison
```

as opposed to

```
cout << "________E\n" << endl;
```

But it comes out wrong in the console,

```
»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

Please and thank you.

Comment: Your editor seems to use a different character encoding than your console.

Comment: @FrankPuffer I checked it out, and it didn't really solve my problem. I'm trying find out how to print out extended ascii characters